# Используя цикл, сгенерировать на экране четыре UIImageView и лейбла

Tags: swift, uiimage

Задача заключается в следующем: на экране нужно сгенерировать картинки, не обязательно 4. Я сделал это простейшим способом:

```
class GalleryViewController: UIViewController {

let images = [UIImage(named: "Stone"), UIImage(named: "СoughingСat"), UIImage(named: "Rainbow"), UIImage(named: "Eagle")]

let imagesViews = [
    UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 200, width: 170, height: 200)),
    UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 220, y: 200, width: 170, height: 200)),
    UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 450, width: 170, height: 200)),
    UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 220, y: 450, width: 170, height: 200))]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for (index, _) in imagesViews.enumerated() {  
        self.view.addSubview(self.imagesViews[index])
        self.imagesViews[index].image = images[index]
    }
}
```

}

Я просто использую 2 массива. Из одного беру сами картинки, из другого положение. Проблема заключается как раз в том, что я генерирую только 4 картинки, а если надо будет 10, то придется делать лишнюю работу.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы через цикл расчитывать положение картинок, а не вручную и вводить через массивы, чтобы картинки добавлялись автоматически, вне зависимости сколько их.

В качестве бонуса будет хорошо, если ширина картинок будет подстраиваться под размеры экрана устройства. Подозреваю, что это можно сделать с помощью "view.frame.width" и на основе этого можно получить ширину картинки, а на основе ширины высчитывать высоту, но я пока не знаю как это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам будет проще использовать  Collection view , настройте под себя и задайте размер картинки. Когда запустите цикл, то размер будет одинаковый , а за позицию на экране будет отвечать ваше collection view.

Comment: Мне "как проще" в данном случае не подходит. Это задание от преподавателя. И хоть я и могу использовать все доступные способы решения задачи, но по плану обучения я, как бы, еще не должен использовать CollectionView

Comment: Тогда вам нужно придумать алгоритм. Например вы задали положения для 1-й картинки с координатами  x: 30, y: 200 , потом когда 2-я картинка должна появиться на экране , вы вызываете ваш метод с алгоритмом где будут  координаты  Х и У( от 1-й mage) + 20 условных поинтов по оси Х и У.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, решение получилось весьма неожиданным:

```
class GalleryViewController: UIViewController {

//массив с картинками
let images = [UIImage(named: "Stone"), UIImage(named: "СoughingСat"), UIImage(named: "Rainbow"), UIImage(named: "Eagle")]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //задал размер ImageView
    let screenWidth = Double(self.view.frame.size.width)
    let imageWidth = screenWidth / 2 - 10 - 10
    let imageHeight = imageWidth * 1.5

    //initialization of variables for coordinates image
    var imageCoordinateX = 0
    var imageCoordinateY = 0
    var stepY = 0
    var definitionOfPositonImage = 0

    for i in 0...images.count - 1 {

        //если четная
        if i % 2 == 0 && definitionOfPositonImage % 2 == 0 {
            //set the coordinate value
            imageCoordinateX = 15
            stepY += 1

        } else {

            imageCoordinateX = 220

        }
            //сдвиг картинки вниз по Y
            definitionOfPositonImage += 1
            imageCoordinateY = stepY * 170


        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = images[i]

        //чтобы первые две картинки не смещались по Y
        if i == 0 || i == 1 {
            //задание положения и размера картинки
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: imageCoordinateX, y: 50, width: Int(imageWidth), height: Int(imageHeight))

        } else {

            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: imageCoordinateX, y: imageCoordinateY, width: Int(imageWidth), height: Int(imageHeight))
        }

        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

}
```

Пришлось создать искусственное ограничение. Ограничение реализовано таким образом, что картинки выводятся в два столбика, а их координаты зависят от индекса картинки в массиве. Координата х фиксированная т.е. 0-ая картинка выводится в правую часть экрана, 1-ая в левую. Координата Y изменятся таким образом, что от 0-ой, 2- ей и т.д. картинки делается шаг определенного размера по этой числовой прямой. Сдвиг по Y реализуется так: если картинка находится слева, то к переменной "stepY" прибавляется 1-ца. Это сделано для того, чтобы после каждой левой(0-ой, 2-ой, 4-ой) картинки расстояние увеличивалось на эту картинку. То есть, если после нулевой картинки координата Y равна 170, то после второй она уже будет равна 170*2, после третьей 170*3. А переменная "definitionOfPositonImage", как вы поняли, нужна для определения четности картинки.